# Kentico Import Toolkit 8.1

Tags: import, document, kentico

I am currently using the Kentico Import Toolkit to create documents in the tree.
At this point, I have imported around 100 documents using the toolkit, and they are all located at the correct place in the tree. Now the issue/concern that I had was, as I have imported these documents, my spreadsheet has been updated, so extra fields and data were added, so how do I go about importing this extra data into the currently existing documents? Also just bear in mind I don't want other fields or data to be affected by this, as some of the documents were updated with some other content by the content editors using CMS Desk, which isn't available in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import toolkit is not the right tool to achieve this task. Even if you select "Import new and overwrite existing pages" it'll overwrite most of your columns. Actually it only preserves system and id columns from the existing documents - all other columns get overwritten.

Either you can write a piece of custom code or you can try following:

- Open SSMS and navigate to the coupled table of your page type (something like CONTENT_MyDocType). This is where your custom columns are stored.
- Right click -> Edit top 200 rows
- Click "Show SQL Pane"
- Adjust the columns, `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` clause to match your excel file, re-run the query
- Select desired rows in your excel file and copy them to clipboard
- Paste the data in the SSMS

Answer (score 3):

rocky is right, Import Toolkit is meant for importing complete objects, not partial/continuous update.

You could map the fields that you know are not changed in the spreadsheet to a SQL query selecting the value from the target database.

To achieve this, just insert `#<target>` at the beginning of the SQL select statement you will be mapping the field to.

It will be rather laborious though and it also requires certain knowledge about the nature of the spreadsheet changes.